# UILabel tap working in simulator but not in iphone

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer, ios7

In my ios appliation there is a label which is hidden and is displayed when button is clicked and when user taps on label it should give a alertview. For the user to interact with label i enable userinteraction enabled and number of tap gestures to 1 its working in simulator but not on iphone simulator works on ios6 and iphone on ios7

Answer (score 1):

Why use `UILabel`?

Use `UIButton`

- with title as your text and
- set the button type to custom
- making the background color `clearcolor`.
- Also set the action in `touchupinside`

Comment: even the button intraction is not working i tried that way too

Comment: when i checked in device running with ios6 its displaying alertview but not on ios7 i even checked whether user interaction is enabled in both cases and returned yes

Comment: does the click event execute? Include the method call for alert

Comment: i kept a break point when tap function is called it doesn't call break point in iOS7  but calls breakpoint in iOS6 n simulator

Comment: well how you set the action to the button?

Comment: inserted button using xib and click and drag for setting action to button

Comment: Check weather the button goes behind any of any view added in ios7

Comment: can you say how to check it